# I'm trying to scrape a website using scrapy but the site structure is inconsistent

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I have to scrape multiple similar pages but on some pages the main content is in a span tag, while on others its inside a p tag. On some pages both tags are used. Is there some way i can write a common script for all pages?

Answer (score -1):

This is not a question we can really answer with the information provided. Nevertheless, if page content is kind of inconsistent (but somewhat consistent) you can always grab every case possible and parse the data afterwards. This will require some good exception management.

I see you are new to the site so try providing more information with examples, what you tried and what is the expected behaviour next time :) .

Comment: This would work as a comment but it's not an answer (as you pointed out already - there's no way to answer such a broad, generic question).